# How to write current timestamp in cassandra column using entity mapper

Tags: java, cassandra

We are using entity mapper to map cassandra table to java object. Ex

```
class Activity
{
   @PrimaryKey
   int id;
   @Column
   Date modifiedDate;
   @Column
   String activityDesc;
}
```

I want to add **modifiedDate** as the current timestamp generated by cassandra node from function **totimestamp(now())**

How can I achieve this with mapper method without using plain CQL insert query. I checked the docs and found **@Computed** supports function but that is just for select queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date modifiedDate;
```

First, remember that Cassandra's `DATE` type maps to `Java.time.LocalDate`.

Second, when using a DB repository framework, you end up making a tradeoff of explicit control for the convenience of not having to build a boilerplate DAL.  In this situation, I've often set the date at object creation time using `LocalDate.now()`.

```
myDataEntity.setDate(LocalDate.now());
```

> current timestamp generated by cassandra node

Third, this shouldn't be too much of a concern today. An enterprise's servers should be configured to the same NTP endpoint, which means that the date/time will be the same regardless of where it is generated.

I could maybe see if it was a full timestamp and milliseconds mattered. But even without NTP, a precision of *date* shouldn't vary much between an app and a database server.

Comment: This is the logic that I am using today but this is causing problem due to race conditions. If multiple updates are coming at same time and if there is some latency between client and cassandra server then above case is failing.

There is possibility to have old modified date set as current one due to above scenario.

Comment: I would like to add modified time to be decided by actual inserted time not the client time.